# Possibility of non-binary balanced incomplete block design

Tags: experiment-design, blocking

Balanced Incomplete Block Design (BIBD) is defined to be a block design which is proper, equireplicate, incomplete and binary such that every distinct pair of treatments appear together $\lambda$ times.

> Is it somehow equivalent to what the name suggests? In other words, is every block design which is balanced and incomplete BIBD?
> Is every proper, equireplicate, incomplete and balanced design necessarily binary?

I wondered over it because that is what the name suggests, however, I could neither prove it nor provide a counter example (especially to the second question).

Comment: What do you mean here by a binary design?

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen A block design with binary incidence matrix, i.e. no treatment occurs in any block twice.